# Git: What to do when you determine your one project is many and not one project?

Tags: git

I started writing a webapp with the backend, then added a REST layer, and finally a frontend.

I've been using a repository all along the way, committing changes as I write them; but now I'm starting to think this is really three projects that should be in separate module repositories; especially since they should all be decoupled from one another.

So my question is; how do I go from a single repository to three different module repositories with what I already have, and only take the changesets for each module into just the module repository for that project?

The idea here would be that someone have the option to checkout these projects individually, or together depending on if they want a single server running the project, or if they want to string it between a couple of seperate VMs; or in the case of the backend API, they can check it out individually to do unit testing.

Is there a way to do this in git?  Are there best practices for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can approach this by using `git subtree split` command as described in [this article](https://lostechies.com/johnteague/2014/04/04/using-git-subtrees-to-split-a-repository/)

Answer (score 1):

- make 4 copies of your repository (original, module1, module2 module3)
- see 'git help filter-branch' for options '--index-filter' and '--subdirectory-filter'

Comment: Here is something from git hub [link] (https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)